# Running a search query on large database - SQLite/Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got a table with over 100k items and I'm busy with away to display and search them, however I've gotten the "cursor window window is full", I understand this is due to the size of the table and have been reading about breaking up the query.

```
 public List<Product> getAllItems(){
        List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int num = cursor.getInt(0);
        for(int x = 1; x < num; x = x + 10000){
            //Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " >= " + String.valueOf(x) + " AND " + KEY_ID + " <= " + String.valueOf(x + 10000);
            cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            // Looping through all the rows and adding to the list
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    Item item= new Item();
                    //Add item to list
                    itemList.add(item);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return itemList;
    }
```

Now this has slightly sped up the query but am I on the right track with this line of thought ?

Comment: I would actually take a look at this the paging library https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html

Comment: How do you fit 100k items on the screen? I do not believe that you actually want to display all of them.

Comment: @CL. Recyclerview for displaying. However I'm looking to only display 100 at a time however it's mainly the searching I think that would be used. I've doing a search query by using the itemname/code but the search query takes just as long.

Comment: @Demonic218 if you haven't, try creating indexes on the columns and or column combinations you are going to use.

Comment: @tyczj - Would you be able to provide an example, I'm struggling to implement this.

Comment: @MikeT - I've added indexes to the columns like you suggested but the query time didn't change by much.

Comment: i agree with this statement, it seems viable